# How to exclude substring of a Template Literal Type?

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I would like to exclude some substring from a Template Literal Type (available since TypeScript 4.1), but I don't know if it's possible.

**Example:**

I can define a type saying *"this string is a tuple-like with 2 or more elements"*, ie something like `'[string, number]'` with this literal type :

```ts
type TupleWithTwoOrMoreElements = `[${string}, ${string}]`;
```

Now, I would like to do the contrary, ie creating a literal type saying *"this is a tuple-like which have less than 2 elements"* by excluding the substring `,` . I thought to do something like this :

```ts
type TupleWithLessThanTwoElements = `[${someStringWithoutCommaOrSpace}]`;
```

I think that it's not possible to write this kind of *"regex-literal-type"*, but I would like to know if someone would be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you please add more constraints/requirements with examples what you want to achieve with some expected and non expected results?

Comment: Technically, that is possible, but your original `TupleWithTwoOrMoreElements` type is, unfortunately, unusable for the purpose (maybe someone more experienced will disagree) - `TupleWithLessThanTwoElements` could be constructed with conditional types and `infer` (possibly some recursion up to the depth limit to make the type somewhat versatile), but `${string}`, being a union of all possible strings, includes "A, B", so ", B" can't be sliced out, because the resulting type looks like this: ``[${string}]``

Comment: I agree with @OlegValter. Please take a look on this article https://catchts.com/template-literals

If you provide for us more information, I'd wiling to bet that we will help you

Comment: Very interesting article ! Difficult, but interesting... 

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible (as far as I know) to write a type for "any string without a comma".  However if the string is known in advance, it is possible to create a conditional type that checks if that string contains a comma.

```
type HasComma<S extends string, IfTrue = true, IfFalse = false> = 
  S extends `${string},${string}` ? IfTrue : IfFalse;
```

```
type A = HasComma<','> // true
type B = HasComma<'string'> // false
type C = HasComma<'[string, number]'> // true
```

So given a literal string, we can validate it and make sure that it is a tuple with only one element.

```
type ValidateOneTuple<S extends string, IfValid = S, IfInvalid = never> = 
  HasComma<S, IfInvalid, S extends `[${string}]` ? IfValid : IfInvalid>
```

```
type A = ValidateOneTuple<'[string, number]'> // never
type B = ValidateOneTuple<'[string]'> // "[string]"
type C = ValidateOneTuple<'[str,ing]'> // never
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5b5w)

Comment: Which means that while you can't represent a `TupleWithLessThanTwoElements` as a *specific* type, you can represent it as a constraint on a generic type and use a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVnLZN) to validate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it. I had the idea of explicitly allowing some chars, but that is not possible because you can't say `char "x" of any length`. Regex types are also not possible, and don't seem to be implemented soon. Look at [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) in GitHub.