# Is there a way to invert the type of a template literal?

Tags: typescript, typescript-template-literals

For example, we have a string that must start with `/`:

```
type StartsWithSlash = `/${string}`
```

How can we invert this type? Meaning that the type should accept any string as long as the first character is *not* `/`.

Comment: How do you want to *use* the other type? Knowing that would help us answer the question, because they could be answers that work in some situations (for instance, function parameters) but not others.

Comment: Not the exact question, but the same answer: [How to exclude substring of a Template Literal Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66420752/12299000)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I want to use it in an interface for example  interface ITabType {
  navigatePath: MyStringWithoutSlash;
}

Comment: @cyborgx99 - Yeah, I don't think you can do that directly. :-|

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on where/how you want to use it. For instance, you can do it with a function parameter:

```typescript
type StartsWithSlash = `/${string}`;

type OppositeOf<TypeToNarrow, TypeToNegate> = TypeToNarrow extends TypeToNegate ? never : TypeToNarrow;

function example<T extends string>(param: OppositeOf<T, StartsWithSlash>) {
    console.log(param);
}

example("works");
example("/fails");  // <== Error as desired
```

Caveat ─ this only works with arguments with literal types. The above have literal types because they're literals, but in the example below there is no error, because TypeScript infers `str`'s type as `string`.

```
let str = "/should-fail-but-doesn't";
example(str); // <== No error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

This solution works when the type is for a function parameter, though that is a fairly special and restricted case. I don't think you can do it more generally.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66420752/12299000) asks for a similar (though different) thing, and its answer (use a branded type) may be a more reliable solution, depending on how you want to use this.